# Как передавать данные между двумя модулями в питон?

Tags: python, классы

Есть класс с GUI, где GUI помогает отображать tkinter и есть класс логики.
т.е. на выходе имеем.

design.py
main.py

Как бы я не пытался сделать что-то типа design -> main -> design
постоянно вылазят ошибки, то импорта то еще чего-нибудь.

Может, кто нибудь написать, как правильно элементарно с Enrty() передать информацию в main, там ее обработать любым методом и вернуть обратно в design в какую-нибудь Label.

Или это возможно только design - > main (сохраняем результат в файл) -> design (читаем файл)

design.py

```py
from tkinker import *
import main

var=''

def setty():    
    var_m = main.m_class.getty()
    var = var_m

window.Tk()
window.title('Main')
window.geomerty('400x400')

button0 = Button(window, command = setty)

lb0 = Label(window, text = var)

lb0.pack()
button0.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

main.py

```py
from tkinter import *
import design

class m_class:

    __init__(self):
        pass

    def getty():
        getting = 'Hello World'
        return getting
```

Comment: Во-первых, у вас путаница в понимании разницы между классами и модулями. Во-вторых, данные между модулями не передаются. Вместо этого нужное содержимое из разных модулей импортируется в рамках одного процесса и после этого уже нет разницы, были ли эти классы импортированы из разных модулей, или изначально были в одном. В третьих, нужно разбираться конкретно по вашей задачей. Приводите пример кода, который у вас не работает, мы вам поможем его исправить. А то так не ясно, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: Извиняюсь да, перепутал. Мне нужно, как то с одного модуля, передать информацию другому и вернуть ее первому.

Comment: Ещё раз повторюсь: данные между модулями не передаются. Напишите ваш код, чтобы было понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Добавил код в шапку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, в вашем коде проблема не с "передачей значения из класса в класс", а несколько других проблем разной степени серьёзности.

```
from tkinker import *
```

Тут у вас опечатка в слове `tkinter`, будет ошибка импорта

```
window.Tk()
```

Тут вы, очевидно, хотели написать `window = Tk()`

```
window.geomerty('400x400')
```

Опечатка в слове `geometry`

```
var=''

def setty():    
    var_m = main.m_class.getty()
    var = var_m
```

Так делать нельзя. Если переменная объявлена вне функции, то нельзя просто так взять и записать в неё значение внутри функции. Это ограничение можно обойти с помощью ключевого лова `global`. Но лучше этого не делать, т.к. в 95% случаев использование `global` означает, что выбрано неудачное решение.

```
class m_class:

    __init__(self):
        pass
```

Пропущено `def` перед `__init__`. Ну и если у вас метод `__init__` пустой, то он вообще не нужен.

Кроме того, у вас перекрёстный импорт - в `main` вы импортируете `design`, а в `design` - импортируете `main`. Так делать не надо.

На самом деле, структура вашей программы плохо продумана. Должен быть один главный запускаемый файл, в котором должен запускаться `window.mainloop()`, а остальные модули сами по себе ничего не должны выполнять, они должны только предоставлять ресурсы (классы и функции).

С учётом вышесказанного, я бы реализовал всё так:

design.py

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label


class App:

    def __init__(self, getty):
        self.getty = getty
        window = Tk()
        window.title('Main')
        window.geometry('400x400')
        lb0 = Label(window, text='')
        self.label = lb0
        button0 = Button(window, command=self.setty, text='Кнопка')
        lb0.pack()
        button0.pack()
        self.window = window

    def setty(self):
        var = self.getty()
        self.label.config(text=var)

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
```

main.py

```
from design import App


class m_class:

    @staticmethod
    def getty():
        getting = 'Hello World'
        return getting


app = App(getty=m_class.getty)
app.run()
```

На самом деле, не самая удачная структура, но это максимально соответствует вашему вопросу.